# Exception:bus.bus unavailable in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I having some error in the server that is

```
File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo_8_test/addons/bus/bus.py", line 188, in poll    
raise Exception("bus.Bus unavailable") Exception: bus.Bus unavailable
```

Because of this I lost the context value and some variable value during the execution of program on server.

Comment: In your .conf file did you set the port 8072 for longpolling?

Answer (score 0):

In your nginx.conf file, add below lines:

```
location /longpolling {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8072;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;
}
```

Comment: I sitll get the error even with that. I have HTTPS & certbot, would that confuse things?

Answer (score 0):

in your odoo.conf file please specify these settings

```
proxy_mode = True
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 60
limit_time_real = 120
workers = 2
```